# Can deterministic and stochastic models be used to models different parts of the same phenomenon?

Tags: biophysics, stochastic-processes

A biological phenomenon including two different causally dependent phenomenon occurs in the cell. (Phenomenon2 initiates as a result of phenomenon1). Phenomenon1 and phenomenon2 are linked with feedback loops.

The entire phenomenon is wished to be mathematically modeled. Phenomenon2 is already modeled with a deterministic model including 3 PDEs. Since phenomenon1 and phenomenon2 are linked with feedback loops, they will be connected to mathematically model the phenomenon in its entirety.

Can phenomenon1 be modeled with a stochastic model? If not please explain why.

Initial conditions are already defined, and there is limited/countable number of variables.

Note1: This question is asked in [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/can-deterministic-and-stochastic-models-be-used-to-models-different-parts-of-the?noredirect=1#comment190148_104821), and suggested to move here.
Note2: I have no experience on stochastic models other than a general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing impossible in principle about a combination of stochastic and deterministic behaviour. Indeed large amounts of modelling in science involve some such combination, because whenever there is a stochastic element there are also deterministic things going on.

To get a more complete answer for your specific case you would have to provide more details of the phenomena in question.

Try looking up "Monte Carlo method" .